# Create a list item when item is created in another list

Tags: sharepoint-designer

Basically i want to add items to 1 list based on columns from another list. so for example say i have 2 list,
List 1 and List 2. List 1 has 5 colunms; Name, Age, id , Location, Manager. List 2 contains 3 colums; Name, Location, Manager.

What i want to do is when an item is added to list 1 i want to automatically add a new item to list 2. List 2 colunms should be autopopulated by the colunm values from list 1.

Anyone any ideas how i could acheive this i have tried using lookup values and i also tried using a workflow but cant seem to get it working properly. i am new to sharepoint.

Comment: I am essentially trying to do the same thing, is there anyway to do it without sharepoint designer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You definitly can do this with workflows.

Just create a list-workflow on List1 which creates a new Item on List2 with the given item values and set the workflow to "Start workflow automatically when an item is created".

All you need for this task is the SharePoint Designer.

If you do so, also consider the occurence of changes in List1 or List2.

Comment: For some reason I didn't see this the first time I looked to do this (being blind ftw?). Thansk!

Answer (score 0):

you could also just have two seperate views of the same list, thats probably the least amount of work for this.

if there was a permissions challenge for that situation, you could create the seperate view, then add a new current navigation link to that view with different permissions through changing the "audience" under the navigation settings