# Copy element action

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-online, workflow

I am currently trying to implement a custom workflow where one can copy a list item in sharepoint 2013.

This is what I did to achieve this:

1. add a **custom workflow** ("copy list element")

   - workflow version: sharepoint 2010
   - start setting: allow manual start
   - workflow:

     - action: "Copy listelement in c̲u̲r̲r̲e̲n̲t̲_̲el̲e̲m̲e̲n̲t̲ to l̲i̲s̲t̲n̲a̲m̲e̲"
2. add a **button** to the ribbon

   - custom action ("copy element")

     - Actiontype: initiate worfklow ("copy list element")

But what happens now is that everytime I click the button, the user sees a new page: "Start workflow" with two buttons "Start" and "Cancel". What I rather would like to have: when the user clicks the new button the workflow should start without asking.

Comment: As far as I know this is because you choose SharePoint 2010 as Workflow version. If you choose 2013 there will be no prompt.

Comment: You can create a list item and after that you delete the other one.

Comment: there are a bunch of tutorials out there. Try http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/50059/create-a-list-item-when-item-is-created-in-another-list or http://www.documentmanagementworkflowinfo.com/sharepoint-2013/sharepoint-designer-workflow-create-update-list-item-actions.htm to get started. It is not necessary to create a new answer if there so many out there

Comment: maybe this one helps? http://www.wonderlaura.com/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=223

Comment: @Patrick Thanks for the suggestion but it is not working - see here:
http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/172285/sharepoint-2013-workflow-not-working

Comment: Commented in the new question. You have also updated this question...