# Sharepoint 2013 - Workflow not working

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-online, workflow

A specific part in my sharepoint 2013 workflow does not work.

I have a custom list in my sharepoint website and I've created a custom workflow for this list to copy an element. To achieve that I have the following action:

---

**Step 1**

- Mail me "Workflow started"
- Create Element in "Current List" (Output in Variable: Create)

  - List: Current List

    - Field: Required field Xy
    - Value: This element: Required field Xy
- Mail me "Workflow ended"

---

Interestingly I receive the first mail but not the second. And of course the element is not created. But the workflow is pretty simple: Create an element and use the values of the current selected element.

[image]

Comment: What is the Workflowstatus? Is it "Abgeschlossen"? Are all required fields in the new list item? Also the values have to fit for the fields. So e.G. a date field has to have a date as value.

Comment: Are list permIssion broken ?

Comment: And whats the error you recieve

Comment: @TaranGoel See answers for the solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Patrick mentioned in his [comment](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/172285/sharepoint-2013-workflow-not-working/172408#comment178609_172408), the solution was to check my field settings. I've had a column which had the settings

- this column requires information
- force explicit values

I disabled both and now the workflow is working again.

Comment: If you found your solution you shoud either mark your own answer as the answer or choose another answer as the answer, so people can find it in the future

Comment: @Patrick Marking an own answer as a solution is possible 18 hours after posting it. That's why it was not marked yet =)

Answer (score 2):

I will give you a step by step guide how to create a new item in a new list. It is more a "How to create your first workflow", but should help anyway. I posted it now also in my blog if you would like to read it there again: https://afrait.com/blog/how-to-create-your-first-2013-workflow-de-en/

Lets go, (Pictures in German), but it tried to write it for english too:

1. Go to your site and click on "Websiteinhalte" (Site Contents) and then click on "App hinzufügen" (add an app)

[image]

2. Next under the section "Beachtenswert" (Noteworthy) click on "Benutzerdefinierte Liste" (Custom List) (1). Then type in a name for the list (2) and click on "Erstellen" (Create) (3).

[image]

3. You will now get redirected to the "Websiteinhalte" (Site Contents). Click now on the title or tile of your new list.

[image]

4. Click in the ribbon on "Liste" (List) (1) and then click on "Liste bearbeiten" (Edit List) (2).

[image]

5. Maybe a popup will now show up because SharePoint Designer will open. Click on "Zulassen" (Accept).
6. Now click on "Neu" (New) (1), then type in a Name (2), select SharePoint 2013 Workflow (3) and click on "OK" (4)

[image]

7. Next click on "Aktion" (Action) (1) and search for "Listenelement erstellen" (Create List item) and click on that. (2)

[image]

8. Click on "diese Liste" (this list) (1) and select the current list (2).

[image]

9. Select now the Title column (1), click on "Ändern" (Change) (2), type in a value (3), click on "OK" (4) and click again on "OK" (5).

[image]

10. Click now in the last section of the workflow (1), then on "Aktion" (Action) (2) and click on "Gehe zu einer Stufe" (Go to stage) (3).

[image]

11. Select "einer Stufe" (to stage)

[image]

12. And then "Ende des Workflows" (End of workflow)

[image]

13. Now click on "Veröffentlichen" (Publish) and your workflow is done.

[image]

14. Now you create a item in your list (I called it "Nummer 1") and then you have to click on the ellipses (...) and click on Workflows.

[image]

15. Now click on the new created link for your workflow.

    **Note:** We didn't change the start options of the workflow. So in this case we have to start it manually.

[image]

16. After a page refresh you should be able to see the new created item from the workflow.

[image]

17. If you want to see the details of your workflow you can click on "Stufe 1" (Stage 1).

[image]

18. There you can see the details about your workflow.

[image]

Hope this will help. I think it is a sort of "How to create your first workflow", but maybe it will help you.

Comment: In your particular case you should check the permissons in your list, the field settings and the user which runs the workflow.

Answer (score 0):

What I see is you are setting a field value. Can you please elaborate.Its not clear. If you are trying to set some value to a field, you should use **Set Field value** action.

Comment: I set the fields of the element that I create in the current list. When you create an element as workflow then you can set the values of this element (it's the same action). I added a screenshot, but it is german language.

Comment: yup, you need to check if you are inserting the right values to each field and no required field is empty. You can set some default value for the required field by going in list settings. Try running the workflow again.